# pg_restore: [compress_io] could not uncompress data: invalid block type

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump, pg-restore

I'm getting this error when I restore a Postgres backup from another server:

*pg_restore: [compress_io] could not uncompress data: invalid block type*

I haven't found much online about what that error means. Except of this [discussion](http://postgresql.nabble.com/parallel-pg-restore-WIP-patch-td1991346.html).

Is it a problem with the backup file? Is it corrupted? Or is there anything that I need to do in order for the target database to read the block type?

---

This is part of a script running in crontab for creating the backup: ...

```
if /usr/pgsql-9.1/bin/pg_dump -Fc -Z 9 -U postgres $PG_DATABASE -p $PG_PORT --schema=$SCHEMA > $PG_BACKUP_FOLDER/notus_dump_$NOW-$SILO.backup 2>/tmp/pg_dump.err
```

... And this is the command that restores it:

```
/usr/pgsql-9.1/bin/pg_restore -v -U postgres -p $PG_PORT -C -e -d $PG_DATABASE -n $SCHEMA [backup file]
```

All variables resolve correctly. The problem is on restore, it starts restoring but it exits with the error in the title.

Comment: Please show the commands to create the backup and restore it.

Comment: This is part of a script running in crontab for creating the backup:
... if /usr/pgsql-9.1/bin/pg_dump -Fc -Z 9 -U postgres $PG_DATABASE -p $PG_PORT --schema=$SCHEMA > $PG_BACKUP_FOLDER/notus_dump_$NOW-$SILO.backup 2>/tmp/pg_dump.err ...


And this is the command that restores it:
 /usr/pgsql-9.1/bin/pg_restore -v -U postgres -p $PG_PORT -C -e -d $PG_DATABASE -n $SCHEMA [backup file]


All variables resolve correctly. The problem is on restore, it starts restoring but it exits with the error in the title.

Comment: @wildplasser thanks for editing, luck of experience at my side

Comment: No sweat. WRT the question: either the dumpfile is damaged or truncated, or you ran into a bug (in pgdump or libz). I would start by trying other versions of pg_restore and -eventually- pg_dump. Changing the compression-level could also work. BTW: have you copied or transported the dumpfile in any way?

Comment: I have yes. We copy dump files to a NAS server and I copied it from there. All copying through scp. I also tried another backup and it failed with "could not uncompress data: invalid stored block lengths" but this time when restoring a different object. It definitely needs some deeper investigation, I will start by changing the compression level.

Comment: The commands look fine except for the weird `if` before pg_dump. As they are known to work, I'd suspect a systemic problem first.

Comment: I decreased compression level to 7 and the generated backup would restore in target server. But I think that this was pure luck. I compared the size in bytes between the backup file on the source server before copy and the one on NAS and it was different. I then restored both backups and compared table row counts and they were different too. So, I think that the problem is with copying the file and not its compression level. When I copied the file to NAS using rsync instead of scp, file sizes matched and I was able to restore the compression 9 dump file.

Comment: @DanielVérité the if was part of the script, I shouldn't have copied it

Comment: @wildplasser thank you for pointing me to the right direction. I am not sure how can I credit you the right answer, always respecting the rules??

Comment: From the symptoms, it looks like the NAS hardware/firmware has been lying to the software. This happens often: the controller accepts a flush or fsync, or write barrier, but in fact postpones it. BTW: the buffering could also take place at the client (writer) side. Be careful out there!